# NSArray objectAtIndex index 1 bounds beyond [0,0]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, nsindexpath

My problem is that the first cell in each section works but if I have another cell in that section (index 1) it just crashes with that error.

I realize this question has been asked many times, but I have referenced the other questions and not have helped, I am getting the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

And the class where this problem is:

HERE IS MY .H,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface SidebarViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuItems;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *fitnessItems;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *fitnessItemsImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *settingsItems;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *settingsItemsImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allItems;


@end
```

HERE IS MY .M,

```
#import "SidebarViewController.h"
#import "UIColor+FlatUI.h"


@interface SidebarViewController ()

@end

@implementation SidebarViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_menuItems = @[@"Home"];
_fitnessItems = @[@"Find Exercises",@"Workouts",@"Build Workouts"];
_settingsItems = @[@"Account", @"Preferences"];


}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return [self.menuItems count];
        break;
    case 1:
        return [self.fitnessItems count];
        break;
    case 2:
        return [self.settingsItems count];
        break;

    default:
        break;
 }

return 3;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (section == 0) {
    return 0;
}
else
    return 25;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
/* Create custom view to display section header... */
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 4, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:15]];
label.textColor = [UIColor peterRiverColor];
/* Section header is in 0th index... */
if (section == 1) {
    label.text = @"Fitness";
}
else if (section == 2) {
    label.text = @"Settings";
}
else
    label.text = nil;
[view addSubview:label];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cloudsColor]]; //your background color...


    return view;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Home";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [_menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home-25.png"];

}
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [_fitnessItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"torso-25.png"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"weightlift-25.png"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barbell-25.png"];
    }
}
if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [_settingsItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user_male4-25.png"];
    }
    else
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"archive-25.png"];
}

UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cloudsColor];
bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;

return cell;
}


- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{
// Set the title of navigation bar by using the menu items
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
destViewController.title = [[_menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] capitalizedString];


    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
    SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

    swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

        UINavigationController* navController =    (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
    };

 }





}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Test" sender:nil];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your `prepareForSegue:` method.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
destViewController.title = [[_menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] capitalizedString];
```

For example selected index path is 1.2 => your code is calling `[_menuItems objectAtIndex:2]` that raises the error.

Actual solution depends on what you want to do. If you want to perform the seague only when tapping on cell from first section you should change your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Test" sender:nil];

}
```

Otherwise you should change the `destViewController.title = ...` accordingly.

A tip that might want to help you find this kind of errors would be to [set the breakpoints on exceptions](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions).